# log4j2 to configure logging level to all for particular class and restrict the rest of the classes to "error" level

Tags: log4j2

I have a requirement to write all logs from specific package (com.kat.util) and restrict the rest of the classes should only log "error". how can i achieve that ?

I tried the below snippet, but its not working

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.kat.util">
        <AppenderRef ref="writer" level="all"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="writer"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: _"but its not working"_ - _How_ is it not working? Nothing is logged, loglevel is always max "error", loglevel is any for all ... ? How do you create loggers in code?

Comment: Thanks @Fildor, for the response.. I managed to solve by adding the below


<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.kat.util"  level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="writer"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="writer"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve, by adding the below

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.kat.util" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="writer" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="writer"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```